# AC3 codec for MX Player

Tags: media-player

Since the latest MX Player upgrade, AC3 is not included because of some licensing issues. How can I add a codec to MX player?
I did search the play store, but all codecs seem to be connected to a specific player.

Comment: I don't think you can. The "codec" plugins for MX Player are only optimized versions of the built-in codecs, for particular hardware. If MX won't pay the patent fees to include AC3, they can't ship it at all, whether built-in or as a plugin.

Comment: @DanHulme you can, see below.

Comment: Download the codec from here : http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/mx-player/mx-player-custom-codec-dts-support-t2156254

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open mxplayer, and go to the settings-decoder. On the bottom you will see "download user codec" and recomendation "download neon arm7". Then, just follow the instructions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the Codecs for the previous version.
Go into MX Player - Help - FAQs. This links you through to their website. Look down the list and find question regarding Codecs. Follow links through to Custom Codecs and this takes you to XDA Developers where the Codecs and installation instructions can be found. Its very simple from this point.

Also here is the link to the XDA forum thread for the [MX player](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/mx-player/mx-player-custom-codec-dts-support-t2156254) for codec support.

Comment: You should supply the link to the MX Player thread on XDA

Comment: @HasH_BrowN http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/mx-player/mx-player-custom-codec-dts-support-t2156254

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed that was a suggestion for an edit to crdent's answer, which still didn't get edited.

Answer (score 3):

Just download the previous version of MX player 1.7.32 as Apk file. Here's the link http://www.androiddrawer.com/22713/download-mx-player-app-apk/ and install and don't upgrade to the latest version by changing the setting of Google play not to update automatically.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [VLC Player on Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc) for such files. It supports AC3 codec and .mkv files too.